# Unexpected behavior of ++myCount

Tags: programming

I'm new to Arduino and C.
This behavior is not what I'd expect:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
while ( ! Serial );

int myCount = 0;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    myCount = min( ++myCount, 8 );
    Serial.print( myCount );
    Serial.print( "  " );
}
```

I would expect:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  8  8
```

But I get:

```
2  4  6  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
```

Why is my code counting by 2?

Comment: Because of the way the min() function is implemented, avoid using other functions inside the brackets, it may lead to incorrect results: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/min/

Comment: if min is a *macro* such as `#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))` think about what happens when you *expand* `min( ++myCount, 8 )` .... you get `((++myCount)<(8)?(++myCount):(8))` - however, I didn't think it was a macro, so that's odd

Answer (score 5):

Jaromanda X is indeed correct - `min()` is defined on line 92 of [Arduino.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Arduino.h), thusly:

```
#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))
```

Therefore when the `++mycount` is substituted for the `a`, it is in fact substituted *twice*, in both the `(a)<(b)` *and* the `(a):(b)`, leading to the increment by 2, each time `min(++mycount,8)` is executed.

As VE7JRO mentions, as it is defined in this way, the [reference for `min(x,y)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.Min) states:

> **Warning**
>
> Because of the way the min() function is implemented, avoid using
>   other functions inside the brackets, it may lead to incorrect results
>
> ```
> min(a++, 100);   // avoid this - yields incorrect results
>
> min(a, 100);
> a++;            // use this instead - keep other math outside the function
> ```

As the second example states, keep *any* incrementing *outside* of the `min()` macro.

Alternatively, I think that you could use the `inline` function to workaround this issue:

```
#undef min
inline int min(int a,int b) {return ((a)<(b)?(a):(b)); }
```

Because `inline` provides a *real* function call (with parameters) it avoids the use of macros and substitution, which gives rise to the issue that you encountered.

`inline` is a much better (safer) way to implement the functionality provided by macros, in many cases. For more information, see [Inline functions in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/) or read a C++ reference.

Comment: The advantage of using a macro is it is type agnostic. You can use it with float, double, char, int, long, signed or unsigned, and it doesn't care.

Comment: esp8266 has min() as template function.